# Adding file export option removes filters & items per page

Tags: datatables

When I added the file export option to my datatable, for some reason it hides the "items per page" select box and the filters (also select boxes).

Here is my code:

```
$('#details').DataTable({
            "lengthChange": true,
            "pageLength": 50,
            "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, -1], [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, "הכל"]],
            "language": {
                "processing": "מעבד...",
                "lengthMenu": "הצג _MENU_ פריטים",
                "zeroRecords": "לא נמצאו רשומות מתאימות",
                "emptyTable": "לא נמצאו רשומות מתאימות",
                "info": "_START_ עד _END_ מתוך _TOTAL_ רשומות",
                "infoEmpty": "0 עד 0 מתוך 0 רשומות",
                "infoFiltered": "(מסונן מסך _MAX_  רשומות)",
                "infoPostFix": "",
                "search": "חפש:",
                "url": "",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "ראשון",
                    "previous": "הקודם",
                    "next": "הבא",
                    "last": "אחרון"
                }
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: You have messed up the `dom` attribute, it should be `dom: 'Blfrtip'` (for the default layout including buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. There were 2 problems:
The first one, as @davidkonrad sait, the `dom` attribute should have been set to `Blfrtip`.
The second one is that my table lacked the `tfoot` attribute.